# How to implement "tar uf" in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, gzip, tar

As described in title. The web server receive one .tgz file stream, transform it to a new .tgz file. My solution now is to save the original file.tgz stream to temp dir, create new file in the temp dir then pack temp dir up. I use `fstream`, `zlib` and `tar` modules.

How to append new files to original tgz file without creating a temp dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [`gzappend`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzappend.c), an example in the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) distribution, for the general approach to appending to a gzip file. However you will need to also strip the last 1024 bytes of zeros (when uncompressed), which mark the end of the tar file. Then you can append your new entries, compressing them, and put the end marker on.

Comment: > also strip the last 1024 bytes of zeros

Comment: But the read stream is not editable before the 'stream end' event. 

I'm thinking about how to implement in 'Node.js' way

Comment: I don't know what the "Node.js" way is. In any case, the `gzappend` code can be adapted to copy the original gzip stream to a new stream. You don't need to "edit" the original stream.